# ggcorrplot: insignificant values

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

I've created a *corrplot* using `ggcorrplot` with the following code:

```
library(ggcorrplot)

corCN <- subset(csfBL, BL_Diaggroups==1, 
                select=c("log_ab38", "log_ab40", "log_ab42", "ABratio", "log_YKL", "logNgcomplete", "log_NFL"))

colnames(corCN) <- c("Aß 1-38","Aß 1-40", "Aß 1-42", "Aß 42/40", "YKL-40", "Ng", "NFL")

corrCN <- cor(corCN, method=c("spearman"), use="complete.obs")
p.matCN <- cor_pmat(corCN, method=c("spearman"), use="complete.obs")

CNcorrplot <- ggcorrplot(corrCN, type="lower", lab=TRUE, ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_classic,
                          p.mat=p.matCN, insig ="blank")

CNcorrplot2 <- CNcorrplot + ggtitle("CN") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

And the plot looks like this.

[image: Corrplot]

The only thing I want to change is that the insignificant values have "NS" in them or are totally blank (so no 0 displayed). Actually I would need some kind of code saying:

```
if insig=TRUE, lab=FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a modified version of `ggcorrplot` called `myggcorrplot` with the new `lab.notsig` option (the label for not significant correlations).
Download the file [here](https://pastebin.com/rBDi2Hex) and save it in your working directory as `myggcorrplot.r`.
Then, run the following code:

```
library(ggcorrplot)  
library(mvtnorm)
# A toy dataset
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
p <- 7
A <- matrix(runif(p^2)*2-1, ncol=p) 
Sigma <- cov2cor(t(A) %*% A)
corCN <- data.frame(rmvnorm(n, mean=rep(0,p), sigma=Sigma))
colnames(corCN) <- c("Aß 1-38","Aß 1-40", "Aß 1-42", "Aß 42/40", "YKL-40", "Ng", "NFL")

corrCN <- cor(corCN, method=c("spearman"), use="complete.obs")
p.matCN <- cor_pmat(corCN, method=c("spearman"), use="complete.obs")

# Load the myggcorrplot function
source("myggcorrplot.r")
# Set in the lab.notsig option the label for not significant correlations
CNcorrplot <- myggcorrplot(corrCN, type="lower", lab=TRUE, 
              ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_classic,
              p.mat=p.matCN, insig ="blank", lab.notsig="NS")

CNcorrplot2 <- CNcorrplot + ggtitle("CN") + 
                   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 
CNcorrplot2
```

[image]

Comment: WOW! You are awesome :)

Comment: @Marco Sandri Thank you for providing `myggcorrplot()`, nice workaround! Would you have any idea why I can not add a theme within your example using `ggtheme = my_ggtheme()` as usually in  `ggcorrplot()`?

Comment: @mavericks Hi. Could you send me (for example by pastebin.com) the code you are trying to use with `myggcorrplot` ?